# Using Keras and TensorFlow building LSTM Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We learned about using Keras to build LSTM model in class, however, I'm still confused on how should you set up the layers for the model. What are the rules and what does each step means?

For instance, for the code below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense
numUnits = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add( LSTM(units=numUnits,return_sequences=True,
                input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)) )
model.add( Dropout(0.2) )

model.add( LSTM(units=numUnits) )
model.add( Dropout(0.2) )

model.add( Dense(units=1) )
model.compile( loss='mean_squared_error' )
```

What does each of these steps mean? Do we need to use dropout for after setting each layer? Does it always has to end with a Dense layer?

Answer (score 0):

The first layer that is added to the model is an LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) layer, which is a type of recurrent neural network layer that is well suited to process sequential data.

The Dropout layer is used to randomly drop a fraction of the units during training, which helps to prevent overfitting. It drops a fraction of units based on its input parameter.

The dense layer is the most common type of layer in a neural network, and it is typically used to transform the output of the previous layer into a format that is suitable for the task at hand. For example, if the task is a classification task, the dense layer may be used to transform the output of the previous layer into a probability distribution over the classes.

To answer your questions, Dropout layers are not required after every layer, but they are often placed after recurrent layers such as LSTM or GRU to prevent overfitting. The Dense layer is usually the last layer in a model, but it's not completely necessary.